# Saber qual botao invocou a action

Tags: ios, swift

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um pickView que sera igual para duas action, porem essas action tem que realizar passagem de parâmetro , ou seja preciso saber qual botão invocou a action. 
Alguém saberia como resolver este problema ?
Ah tenho dois botões que invocara.
Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma vez que você definiu os dois botões:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnPrimeiro: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnSegundo: UIButton!
```

A sua ação de fato pode ser só uma para *N* botões. Esta ação recebe o próprio botão como parâmetro, então você pode conferir qual dos botões foi pressionado:

```
@IBAction func acaoBotao(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender == btnPrimeiro {
        // Primeiro botão pressionado
    } else {
        // Segundo botão pressionado
    }
}
```

Claro, isso para tanto os botões e a ação ligados pelo *interface builder*.

Comment: Amigo entendi , mas esse btnPrimeiro o que seria ? Algim id ? Ou a outlet ? Obrigado

Comment: É o *outlet* de cada botão seu no *interface builder*. Você faz a ligação tanto do `IBOutlet` quanto do `IBAction`. Dos *outlets* para cada botão e da *action* para os botões.

Comment: Ok irei testar ... Obrigado

Comment: Funcionou amigo, muito obrigado